# How to use PyUpdater

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller, pyupdater

I Have a `main.py` file for my Tkinter app.
I export it to a standalone.exe with Pyinstaller.
I want that when I start the `.exe` to update the .exe if a new version was deployed in the directory where I export my program.
Apparently we can do that with PyUpdater but I didn't find how on StackOverflow.

Comment: Unfortunately, [PyUpdater is no longer supported](https://github.com/Digital-Sapphire/PyUpdater/blob/main/README.md). An alternative is [tufup](https://github.com/dennisvang/tufup), which is based on [The Update Framework (TUF)](https://theupdateframework.io/). Have a look at the [tufup-example](https://github.com/dennisvang/tufup-example) repo to see how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to push updates/patches to a frozen python program, read [this explanation](https://pyupdater-wx-demo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html) in the PyUpdater documentation.

Instead of attempting make your app auto-update (i.e. push updates to frozen apps) a much more straightforward approach would be to use [Inno Setup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).